# Spring MVC x Spring MVC Boot

Tags: java

Qual a diferença entre Spring MVC x Spring MVC Boot?

São a mesma coisa? Existe alguma vantagem em utilizar o segundo?

Obrigada

Answer (score 4):

Spring Boot e Spring MVC são coisas diferentes. O Spring Boot contém o Spring MVC, portanto ao usar ele, você já estará automaticamente usando o Spring MVC.

Só que ele oferece uma vantagem muito importante: usa um conceito chamado Convention over Configuration (Convenção sobre Configuração), então ele já define alguns padrões para permitir que mais rapidamente e facilmente você consiga desenvolver a sua aplicação e colocá-la no ar. Com isso, o número de configurações que você teria que fazer caso fosse usar somente o SprinG MVC vai ser reduzido drasticamente.

Hoje em dia, na minha opinião, não faz mais sentido você começar um projeto novo Spring MVC sem ser com o Spring Boot.

Agora, se você quiser usar Spring MVC e Spring Boot, de um jeito ainda mais fácil e rápido (e inteligente), pode usar o Grails 3. Você vai ter todas as vantagens do Spring MVC e Spring Boot, e ainda mais as facilidades do Grails. Vale a pena experimentar... (www.grails.org).

Comment: "Convention over Configuration (Convenção sobre Configuração), então ele já define alguns padrões para permitir que mais rapidamente e facilmente você consiga desenvolver a sua aplicação e colocá-la no ar" Tem algum link falando mais disso?

Comment: Especificamente sobre Grails, você pode conferir algumas convenções aqui: http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/gettingStarted.html#conventionOverConfiguration

Já sobre o paradigma de convenção sobre configuração de modo genérico: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conven%C3%A7%C3%A3o_sobre_configura%C3%A7%C3%A3o ou https://www.techopedia.com/definition/27478/convention-over-configuration

Comment: Outras convenções seguidas pelo Grails: Ao criar uma classe de domínio, ele já cria um arquivo de testes para você. Se a classe chama Pessoa, então o nome do arquivo será PessoaSpec. Se você cria um controller para a classe pessoa, ele chamará PessoaController. Nada impede que vc altere esses nomes, mas já é uma convenção dele.

Inicialmente ele já define que o banco de dados é o H2, que o framework de testes é o Spock, que usa i18N para fazer internacionalização da aplicação. Tudo você pode trocar, mas para quem está iniciando uma aplicação, já vem tudo pronto para usar.